# Chain rule for $ h : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $h(x,y)=f(g(u,v),-g(u,v))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

In my analysis course we've been dealing strictly with functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and we've been given the following formula for calculating derivative of $f(x(t),y(t))$ w.r.t. $t$:

> $\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}$

Now I'm struggling with following problem:

> Let $f, g : R^2 → R$ be differentiable. Define $h(x, y) = f(g(u, v), −g(u, v))$.
>   Show that $dh = (f_x − f_y)dg$

It seems to me the right approach would be to try to find $\frac{dh}{dg}$. I didn't know how to start, so I tried finding $\frac{dh}{dt}$, where $h(t) = f(x(t),y(t))$ , $x = t$, $y = -t$. Formula above gives: 
$$ \frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{df}{dx} - \frac{df}{dy}\quad \rightarrow\quad dh =(f_x − f_y)dt$$
And since $y(t) = - x(t)$ the result above applies to $h(t) = f(x(t),-x(t))$.

It looks very similiar to what I'm trying to show, but I don't know what to do when the inside functions rely on 2 variables.

Comment: is u a function of x, and v a function of y, i.e., $g(u,v)=g(u(x),v(y))$?  If not something like that the definition is sort of nonsensical, since x and y never get used  in any way.

Comment: @eSurfsnake It isn't mentioned anywhere, I cited the whole problem. I guess this could be a typo? Since I don't understand the problem itself well, I guess I'm not in position to correct it.

Comment: @eSurfsnake The problem statement is indeed rather sloppy. It makes the implicit assumption that $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and then confuses them with $u$ and $v$ in the definition of $h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be helpful in problems like these to introduce intermediate functions: here, the function $\phi: t\mapsto(t,-t)^T$ looks like it’ll help untangle things a bit. It can also be helpful to use positional notation for partial derivatives instead of dummy variable names, which have a tendency to get overloaded. We then have $h = f\circ\phi\circ g$ and $$dh_{\mathbf p} = df_{\phi(g(\mathbf p))} \circ d\phi_{g(\mathbf p)} \circ dg_\mathbf p.$$ If we fix coordinate systems for the domains and ranges of these functions, we can identify the differentials with Jacobian matrices and the chain rule becomes matrix multiplication: $$dh = \begin{bmatrix}f_1&f_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix} dg = (f_1-f_2)\,dg,$$ with the partial derivatives of $f$ evaluated at the point $(g(u,v),-g(u,v))$.

Comment: While I like your clever approach, as I pointed out in a comment to the questioner, if h(x,y) =f(g(u,v), g(u,v)), where does t come in?

Comment: @eSurfsnake Where do you see a $t$ in the problem that is to be solved? I agree that the notation used in the problem statement is rather unfortunate, but a reasonable interpretation can be reverse-engineered for it.

Comment: yes, you are right.  One unnecesary set of dummy variables.